# Unable to grab user form input and send to firebase cloud firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, use-state

## My Issue:

Hey folks, i'm having issues sending user input from a contact form to firebase Cloudstore. I'm not getting a console.error, or any type of noticeable error.

### What I Want:

When user types info into form, pass that data to react state, then push that data to a firebase Cloudstore entry.

### What I've Tried:

1. I can console.log(name, email, message) and get the data that way, but the form is not submitting the data and i'm unsure why.
2. Yelling at it.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { collection, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../firebase";

function ContactForm() {
  // form user info states
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  // show love when form button click
  const showAppreciation = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let target = document.getElementById("form-ty");
    // toggles display properties for hidden element
    target.style.display === "none"
      ? (target.style.display = "block")
      : (target.style.display = "none");
  };

  // contact form onSubmit handle
  const formHandle = async () => {
    try {
      const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "contact-form"), {
        Name: { name },
        Email: { email },
        Message: { message },
      });
      docRef();
      console.log("Document written with ID:", docRef.id);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("Error adding document", e);
    }
  };

  // render to dom
  return (
    <div className="contact-form">
      <form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" onSubmit={formHandle}>
        <input
          id="form-name"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Name"
          onChange={(e) => {
            setName(e.target.value);
          }}
        ></input>
        <input
          id="form-email"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Email"
          onChange={(e) => {
            setEmail(e.target.value);
          }}
        ></input>
        <textarea
          id="form-message"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Your Message"
          rows={5}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setMessage(e.target.value);
          }}
        ></textarea>
        <input
          id="form-submit"
          type="submit"
          placeholder="Submit"
          onClick={showAppreciation}
        ></input>
      </form>

      {/* Thank you : Hidden By Default */}
      <p className="form-thank-you" id="form-ty">
        Wow, you nailed that button press! {<br />}
        {<br />} Form <span>submitted successfully</span> Talk soon :)
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ContactForm;
```

For extra info, here is my firebase config file. (The env file is not the error).

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

// firebase config
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

// Initialize Firebase
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore();
```

Comment: Quick question: why is your form submit element an `input` and not `button` or similar?

Comment: I don't really know... it's just something I picked up. Do you think that might be an issue?

Comment: no, not an issue (but a button might be clearer) -- I think what you need is to use `formHandle` as the `onClick` for your submit button, not `showAppreciation`

Comment: Amazing! It worked! Thanks very much :)

Comment: sure thing! I'll add it as an answer if you can pls accept :)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is to use `formHandle` as the `onClick` for your submit button, not `showAppreciation`.